# Add css file by internal component angular2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have a component for a textbox that I use for all login fields. Inside it I have a switch through I give particular features;
example:

```
case 'password':
    this.textField.nativeElement.secure = true;
```

I created another field inside the switch and I want to assign it a class in the global css because I need to change the color and the text-size only for this case. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically apply a class to an element using this

```
[class.className]="booleanCondition"
```

You can define a global css file and then reference it in multiple components

```
styleUrls: ['./text-box.component.css', '../../../shared/shared-styles.css']
```